# Wordpress Divi - problem with inserting code for Animated Cursor

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, divi

This is my new clear site: [www.talas.me](http://www.talas.me)

And this is what i want to copy: [Awesome Link Hover Effect / Animated Cursor](https://codepen.io/codegridweb/pen/JjorOXq)

```js
(function () {
      const link = document.querySelectorAll('nav > .hover-this');
      const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
      const animateit = function (e) {
            const span = this.querySelector('span');
            const { offsetX: x, offsetY: y } = e,
            { offsetWidth: width, offsetHeight: height } = this,
            move = 25,
            xMove = x / width * (move * 2) - move,
            yMove = y / height * (move * 2) - move;
            span.style.transform = `translate(${xMove}px, ${yMove}px)`;
            if (e.type === 'mouseleave') span.style.transform = '';
      };
      const editCursor = e => {
            const { clientX: x, clientY: y } = e;
            cursor.style.left = x + 'px';
            cursor.style.top = y + 'px';
      };
      link.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('mousemove', animateit));
      link.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('mouseleave', animateit));
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', editCursor);
})();
```

```css
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      cursor: none;
}

.nav-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: #161616;
}

nav {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
}

.hover-this {
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

span {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: "Monument Extended";
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 36px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: transform 0.1s linear;
}

.cursor {
      pointer-events: none;
      position: fixed;
      padding: 0.3rem;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      mix-blend-mode: difference;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.hover-this:hover ~ .cursor {
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(8);
}

@media(min-width: 900px) {
      nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
      }
}

@media(max-width: 900px) {
      nav {
            top: 30%;
      }

      .hover-this {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0;
            display: inline-block;
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
            <nav>
                  <a href="#" class="hover-this"><span>Home</span></a>
                  <a href="#" class="hover-this"><span>Our Story</span></a>
                  <a href="#" class="hover-this"><span>Studio</span></a>
                  <a href="#" class="hover-this"><span>Contact</span></a>
                  <div class="cursor"></div>
            </nav>
      </div>
```

There is problem somewhere and i can't figure out where. As you can see now (when i copy this code correctly) we can't see the cursor on my site.

Can someone tell me what is the problem and how to fix it?
This is very important for my site because the site will be black and white, and this cursor effect is so important to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running that script outside of the Divi system? I'm curious whether it is a conflict with Divi or an issue with the original script/implementation.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know that Divi theme provide a option in theme settings where we can add custom jQuery or javascript so you can directly add over there
this below link may help you to resolve issue
https://divi.space/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-and-jquery-to-divi/